# @Configuration within @Controller or @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have seen the AutoConfiguration classes, that defines `@Configuration` within an `@Configuration` and these are all `static`. Why they should be static? Is it a better way.

What is the difference between the `@Configuration` defined within `@Component` class and stand-alone `@Configuration` class?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definition of `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java) for `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` to find your answer:

```
// Defined as a nested config to ensure WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is not read when not
// on the classpath
@Configuration
@Import(EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ WebMvcProperties.class, ResourceProperties.class })
public static class WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

The auto-configuration classes are defined as nested static classes to prevent Spring's component-scanning from picking them up automatically when the proper annotation has not been used.  So a good rule of thumb would be to define your configuration classes as stand-alone classes if you expect them to be used every time, or as nested static classes if you'd like to isolate them from classpath scanning.